# Checkbox column with Kendo grid

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I wanted to add a checkbox column as first column to below grid. 
Can some one help me how to add it?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("items")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.itemname).Title("Name");
          columns.Bound(p => p.cost).Title("Cost");
          columns.Bound(p => p.stockinhand).Title("Stock in hand");
          columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(100);
      })
     .Pageable()
             .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Server() 
                .Model(model => model.Id(p=>p.Id))
                .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
            )
)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsAdmin ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />")
```

and then on javascript:

```
   $(function () {
    $('#grid').on('click', '.chkbx', function () {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var grid = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid;
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
        dataItem.set('IsAdmin', checked);
    })
})
```

Comment: Using a grid with InLine Edit mode, how do I disable this checkbox until the line goes into edit mode?

Comment: How to add data-label?
I tried with ==> columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsAdmin ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' data-label='Admin Status'/>")

Answer (score 5):

Hi you can add Checkbox in Header and Column like below :

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Status).HeaderTemplate("<input id='selectall' class='chkbx' type='checkbox' onclick='ToggleChkBox(this.checked);' />").ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Width(30);
```

And FInd Checkbox click  like below :

```
//Cell click Checkbox select
$('#Grid').on("click", "td", function (e) {
    var selectedTd = $(e.target).closest("td");
        var grdChkBox = selectedTd.parents('tr').find("td:first").next("td").find('input:checkbox');
        grdChkBox.prop('checked', !grdChkBox.prop('checked'));

});
```

And do Check all checkbox functionality like below :

```
function ToggleChkBox(flag) {
    $('.chkbxq').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', flag);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I normally add a boolean column in the model; like following.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("items")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(p => p.status).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled #= status == true ? checked='checked' : '' # />");
      columns.Bound(p => p.itemname).Title("Name");
      columns.Bound(p => p.cost).Title("Cost");
      columns.Bound(p => p.stockinhand).Title("Stock in hand");
      columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(100);
  })
 .Pageable()
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Server() 
            .Model(model => model.Id(p=>p.Id))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
        )
)
```

And to disable it until you press "Edit" button just add "disabled" in the ClientTemplate. That should do it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can add checkbox in each row with header using this,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Select();
    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);
    columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Discontinued);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Events(ev=>ev.Change("onChange"))
.PersistSelection()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProductID))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Selection_Read", "Grid"))
))
```

Here we use PersistSelection() for persistting selected items across all pages.

If column.Select() gives error or not bind the grid then upgrade your kendo UI version. It will work.